# разборка записи java boolean

Tags: java

Мне не понятно почему после reverse стоит знак вопроса и после boolean двоеточие, помогите пожалуйста

```
 public class BlockTest
    {
    private static int rounds = 3;
    public void feist(int[] a, boolean reverse)
    {
        int round = reverse? rounds: 1;
        int l = a[0];
        int r = a[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < rounds; i++)
        {
            if (i < rounds - 1) // если не последний раунд
            {
                int t = l;
                l = r ^ f(l, round);
                r = t;
            }
            else // последний раунд
            {
                r = r ^ f(l, round);
            }
            round += reverse? -1: 1;
        }
        a[0] = l;
        a[1] = r;
    }
    private int f(int b, int k)
    {
        return b + k;
    }
    public void test()
    {
        int[] a = new int[2];
        a[0] = 100;
        a[1] = 200;
        feist(a, false);
        feist(a, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/963/java-ternary-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` Это тернарный оператор а все это выражение - [Тернарная условная операция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

`:` это часть синтаксиса тернарной операции.

По сути, выражение

```
int round = reverse ? rounds: 1;
```

Это короткая запись следующего кода

```
int round;
if (reverse) {
    round = rounds;
} else {
    round = 1;
}
```